# Timing client side and server side time of a request in ASPX?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, benchmarking

There is an request at my web application that takes a longer time, but I don't know if it is a server side problem or client side problem. Is there an way to timing client side process and server side process of a request in ASPX?

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in your browser's dev console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Glimpse.  It is open source and quite good.  You can get a view of asp.net app performance at different levels.

[glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stopwatch in your code behind: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

And then at the start:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
```

and the end:

```
stopwatch.Stop();
```

and write it to a log